# NSSortDescriptor in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an iOS app and I have data stored in CoreData that I am loading into a UITableView. The data entities have an attribute called `id` which is a string that contains an `A` followed by a number (i.e. "A1" "A2" etc).

When I use this code for sorting, I end up with the table being sorted lexicographically (i.e. "A1" "A10" "A11" "A12" "A2" "A3" etc)

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
```

What I really want is for it to be sorted numerically, as you might expect. How do I go about doing this? I know that a `NSComparator` can be added as an argument to `NSSortDescriptor` but I can't for the life of me get it figured out. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sort descriptors in a (SQLite-based) Core Data fetch request cannot
use custom comparators and only a limited set of "built-in" comparison
methods. This is documented in
[Fetch Predicates and Sort Descriptors](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/PersistentStoreFeatures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH23-SW7) in the "Core Data Programming Guide":

> ... The SQL store, on the other hand, compiles the predicate and sort
>   descriptors to SQL and evaluates the result in the database itself.
>   This is done primarily for performance, but it means that evaluation
>   happens in a non-Cocoa environment, and so sort descriptors (or
>   predicates) that rely on Cocoa cannot work. The supported sort
>   selectors are `compare:` and `caseInsensitiveCompare:`, `localizedCompare:`,
>   `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:`, and `localizedStandardCompare:` (the
>   latter is Finder-like sorting, and what most people should use most of
>   the time). In addition you cannot sort on transient properties using
>   the SQLite store.

Fortunately, there is one that should fit your needs:

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true,
                       selector: "localizedStandardCompare:")
```

`localizedStandardCompare:` does a "Finder-like" comparison and
in particular treats digits within strings according to their 
numerical value.

For **Swift 2.2/Xcode 7.3** and later:

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true
                         selector: #selector(NSString.localizedStandardCompare))
```

Comment: the new format appears to be.. NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedCompare(_:)))

Comment: So, if I understand correctly. SortDescriptor comes with 3 overloads and the overload that includes *comparator* does **not** work with CoreData?

Comment: @DanBeaulieu: Yes, and the selector-based one can only be used with a fixed list of descriptors. The reason is that the predicate (including the sort descriptor) is translated to a SQLite query. – Link updated, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 3):

for swift 4.2

You can sort array using `NSSortDescriptor`

```
let descriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "lastMessageDate", ascending: false)
let sortedResults = arrChatDialogs?.sortedArray(using: [descriptor])
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

`let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "id", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare))`

***hope it helps***

Answer (score 0):

The Swifty way:

```
var arr = ["A1", "A10", "A11", "A12", "A2", "A3"]
arr.sort {dropFirst($0).toInt() < dropFirst($1).toInt()}
```

So you could use that directly, or use it as the basis of the block for your comparator. If you insist on doing this in what is effectively Objective-C, you can use NSString `compare:options:` where the `options:` include `NSNumericSearch`.

Comment: This would work to sort the data *after* fetching them, but not as sort descriptor in a Core Data fetch request.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift3

key is

```
result: Bool = 0 < "string1".localizedCompare("string2").rawValue
```

Use like this

```
[some string array].sorted { return 0 < "string1".localizedCompare("string2").rawValue }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why to bother with obj-c style's `NSSortDescriptor`, In swift we can nicely sort using Swift high order functions - **xcode 8.x swift 3.x**

```
class Person: NSObject {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let age: Int

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.age = age
    }
    override var description: String {
        return "\(firstName) \(lastName)"
    }
}

let a = Person(firstName: "a", lastName: "b", age: 24)
let b = Person(firstName: "c", lastName: "d", age: 27)
let c = Person(firstName: "e", lastName: "f", age: 33)
let d = Person(firstName: "g", lastName: "h", age: 31)
let peopleObject = [d, b, a, c]
//SWIFTY
let sortedByFirstNameSwifty =  peopleObject.sorted(by: { $0.firstName < $1.firstName })
print(sortedByFirstNameSwifty)//prints[a b, c d, e f, g h]


//Objective c way
let firstNameSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "firstName", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedStandardCompare(_:)))
let sortedByFirstName = (peopleObject as NSArray).sortedArray(using: [firstNameSortDescriptor])
print(sortedByFirstName)//prints [a b, c d, e f, g h]
```

Comment: I wanted to make the sort a parameter on a model so I can use it later. Is there a way to make a generic property to hold a sort closure instead of NSSortDescriptor?

Comment: Can you explain ur doubt in detail?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the collection of object with default sorted function as:

e.g. your array of object is like

```
data = [
    {
        name: "Naresh",
        dept: "CSC",
        id: 102
    },
    {
        name: "Rahul",
        dept: "CSC",
        id: 101
    },
    {
        name: "Amar",
        dept: "CSC",
        id: 100
    }
]

//Comparing string key
let sortByName = data.sorted { (model1, model2) -> Bool in
        return (model1.name.localizedCompare(model2.name) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending)
}

/* The ComaprisonResult is default enum whose possible cases are: */
public enum ComparisonResult : Int {
    case orderedAscending
    case orderedSame
    case orderedDescending
}

/*** SORTING ACCORDING TO NUMERICAL VALUE ***/

//Comparing digit key including Int, Double, Float & all
let sortByNumber = data.sorted { (model1, model2) -> Bool in
            return model1.id < model2.id
}

//You can use the shot form of automatic closure as:
let sortByNumber = data.sorted { $0.id > $1.id }

//In the autoclosure the $0 represent first parameter, $1 represent second parameter. The return statement is optional if closure or functions contains only single statement.
```