# Sort items sequentially using Core Data Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sqlite, predicate

**I want to sort items in sequence order as you can see in screenshot attached.** To sort by last word in its name. Eg. Part 1, Part 2,...etc.

```
let request : NSFetchRequest<DisplayHelper> = DisplayHelper.fetchRequest()
        print("type set is : \(type)")
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "type == %@", type)
        request.predicate = predicate
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
        let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
```

[image: Need data in sequence order]

Comment: There is no easy way.  The title is just a string as far as Core Data is concerned and it will be sorted in lexicographic order.  You would need to take the fetch results, parse the title yourself to determine if it ended with a number (and these strings don't exactly end with a number they end with a ")" ) and then apply your own sort.

Comment: Does all names has this pattern that it ends with "(Part -#)? If not then it's probably impossible but otherwise I would consider extracting the part number before saving them in Core Data and store the number in a separate attribute.

Comment: If the prefix is the same for all entries and the goal is to sort "1", "10", "2", ... by their numerical value then `localizedStandardCompare` is what you need. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/30553843/1187415.

Comment: I fixed it using this logic..firstly i extracted only digits and put into array of type <Object, digit>. Making this new array will then be sorted by digit value and then all  these sorted entries will be added on main array that displaying data.